# Listening to userTrackingMode changes on MKMapView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mkmapview, key-value-observing

I have a subclass of UIView which will enable users to click on it and change the state of the property `userTrackingMode`(*MKUserTrackingMode*) on a `MKMapView`.

Think about it like the native `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` which is an `UIBarButtonItem`.
The behavior need to be the same:

- The view will draw or use different shapes according to the `userTrackingMode`'s changes.
- When I click in the UIView, the property will switch between:

---

```
MKUserTrackingModeNone
MKUserTrackingModeFollow
MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading
```

---

**So far, everything is easy, but here is where the real problem comes:**

The `userTrackingMode` can be changed whenever the user moves in the map. It seems that there no way to listen the changes in swift without doing some really ugly hacks.

Here are my searches:

- **MKMapView Delegates**: Especially with this one (`didChangeUserTrackingMode`). Fits perfectly, BUT cannot use it because I need the mapView delegates elsewere (for example in the viewController).
- **KVO**:
  `mapView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "userTrackingMode", options: [.New,.Old], context: nil)`
  Seems not possible because the property is an enum (int), it's not an NSObject, so not possible to listen the changes... unless I totally didn't understood kvo.

Here is the full code trying to use the KVO solution on [gist](https://gist.github.com/havocked/e768573b80a31d5e6d4dd8f37f548240)

Maybe there is another solution ?

Let me know :)

Comment: when you use  MKMapView Delegates in (for example in the viewController) , can you get the CustomView and let it refresh ?

Comment: That would be one possible, hell, the only one solution that would work. But it doesn't seem right ? If there's no other way, I will accept this comment.

Comment: why not ? it's a obvious way to do it .  you want the btn to be general?

Comment: I wanted to create a component wich would not require action from the developer to set manually its state. I wanted something easy to init and reusable. But for now, it looks that setting the property through the delegate inside the viewController is the way to go.